# My website is loading an external JS that I don't know. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

My website is loading JS to links similar to this one:
`https://api.mixpanel.com/engage?data=eyIkdG9rZW4iOiI2NTQwMDNjNmRkZDAzZTg4NzY0MTM4ZTYwMDQ1M2E2NyIsIiRkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6InBpZmdzaXVhcmhsbHFjOXRncGw1OTlqdXJmIiwiJHNCI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiZnJlZSIsImlzTW96YmFyT24iOmZhbHNlLCJpc0RvY2tlZE9uQm90dG9tIjpmYWxzZSwiYnJvd3NlciI6ImNocm9tZSIsIm9zIjoid2luZG93cyIsInBhZ2VPbmJvYXJkaW5nU3RlcCI6InBhZ2UtaG90c3BvdHMiLCJzZXJwT25ib2FyZGluZ1N0ZXAiOiJzZXJwLWhvdHNwb3RzIn19&ip=0&verbose=0`

I cannot find where it is linked from. I saw the site mixpanel.com and looks like they offer a web analytics service or something similar, but I have not any with them. Have I being hacked? What can I do to find witch file is doing the request?

I am almost sure the request is not being made directly for my website; maybe is made by some plugin? How can I be sure? Should I remove it? How?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using a 3rd party service of some kind that uses Mixpanel. That's just a guess. If you open your developer tools in Chrome you should be able to see the request under network. The column 'initiator' might provide you with the who. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think it directly a service, maybe some free plugin. But how can I know witch one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixpanel is a tracking and analytics provider. If your website is hosted on your very own server, controlled by only you, then things to try are:

1) Disable all your browser's extensions. Turn them all off, confirm that it's either still happening of has been resolved. If it's no longer happening, turn them on one by one.

2) Different internet connection. Some poor WiFi hotspots may inject tracking code.

3) Try a different browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari....

If your website is hosted by someone like Wix, SquareSpace, Weebly, etc then this tracking is very likely injected at their level and you will probably not be able to turn this off, but you should be able to get access to the insights in your control panel.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was an extention. Thanks. =D